# Why does an object start to push off strangely at a low speed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I'm making a game in which the player is constantly moving and pushing off the walls. The movement was made like this:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(rb.velocity * normalSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, normalSpeed);
}
```

But there is a problem, if the speed of the object is set less than 2, then it starts to move very badly: stick to the walls, do not push off. What can this be related to and how can it be fixed?

I changed the values of jumping in the physical material, but it didn't help either, there were no more ideas

Comment: Did you maybe mean `rb.velocity.normalized * normalSpeed` ? currently the added force depends on the magnitude of already applied velocity ... so if the object is very slow you also add very little force

Comment: I changed it, but the object still does not move quite correctly and stops after a short period of time. Although it certainly got better

Comment: Have you tried setting velocity instead of adding force?

Comment: I actually tried a lot of things, like yes, I changed rb.velocity directly, but it didn't help. I used Vector3.Reflect before, but the object got stuck in the wall and stopped moving.